# sprintf function in Perl catalyst template

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

Currently when I add this code

```
[%mortgage.amortization_period%]
```

it gives me output as 250000.00
But I need to remove that decimal points from there.
Some times I need to remove only 1 digit after decimal point. So is there any function like sprintf that I can use inside Catalyst template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the function like `sprintf` is  `sprintf`. You can put functions in the stash and call them from TT, and if you want them to be available all the time you can add them to the `TEMPLATE_VARS` in your view.

Comment: can you just give me an example for that

Comment: currently I am assigning an array to the stash and looping it inside the template file so I need sprintf like thing in the template so I can remove the decimals.

Comment: `$c->stash->{format_nodecimal} = sub { sprintf "%.0f", @_ };` then `[% format_nodecimal(mortgage.amortization_period) %]`

Comment: Or `$c->stash->{sprintf} = \&CORE::sprintf;` and `[% sprintf("%.0f", mortgage.amortization_period) %]`

Comment: @hobbs: I can't try it right now, but I'm pretty sure \&CORE::sprintf does not work

Comment: Can you give some examples of expected input and desired output? I believe @Jitesh wants to have 2500.00 become "2500", but to have "2500.10" become "2500.1", and to have 2500.12 stay as "2500.12". If so `sprintf("%.0f", $_[0])` by itself won't do it.

Answer (score 4):

Template Toolkit provides the [format filter](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Filters.html#section_format_format_) for manipulating variables this way:

```
[%- mortgage.amortization_period | format('%.0f') -%]
```